# How to group and create new property in javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object in javascript:

```
 "types": [
    {
      "ProcessCode": "b4919f5a-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",
      "ProcessName": "processX",
      "DocumentCode": 1,
      "DocumentName": "doc1"
    },
    {
      "ProcessCode": "b4919f5a-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",
      "ProcessName": "processX",
      "DocumentCode": 2,
      "DocumentName": "doc2"
    },
    {
      "ProcessCode": "b4919f5a-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",
      "ProcessName": "processX",
      "DocumentCode": 4,
      "DocumentName": "doc4"
    },
   {
      "ProcessCode": "09c27913-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",
      "ProcessName": "processY",
      "DocumentCode": 1,
      "DocumentName": "doc1"
    },
    {
      "ProcessCode": "09c27913-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",
      "ProcessName": "processY",
      "DocumentCode": 2,
      "DocumentName": "doc2"
    }
]
```

How can I group by `ProcessCode` this object to look like this?

```
"types": [
    {
      "ProcessCode": "b4919f5a-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",
      "ProcessName": "processX",
      "Docs": [{
        "DocumentCode": 1,
        "DocumentName": "doc1"
        },
        {
        "DocumentCode": 2,
        "DocumentName": "doc2"
        },
        {
        "DocumentCode": 4,
        "DocumentName": "doc4"
        }
     ]
   },
   {
      "ProcessCode": "09c27913-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",
      "ProcessName": "processY",
      "Docs": [{
        "DocumentCode": 1,
        "DocumentName": "doc1"
       },
       {
        "DocumentCode": 2,
        "DocumentName": "doc2"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
]
```

I haved try with `groupBy` of lodash, but It put ProcessCode as key and not like the stucture I want.

```
 "types": [
    {
     "b4919f5a-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600": {...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `reduce` for grouping and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped objects.

```js
let types = [    {      "ProcessCode": "b4919f5a-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",      "ProcessName": "processX",      "DocumentCode": 1,      "DocumentName": "doc1"    },    {      "ProcessCode": "b4919f5a-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",      "ProcessName": "processX",      "DocumentCode": 2,      "DocumentName": "doc2"    },    {      "ProcessCode": "b4919f5a-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",      "ProcessName": "processX",      "DocumentCode": 4,      "DocumentName": "doc4"    },   {      "ProcessCode": "09c27913-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",      "ProcessName": "processY",      "DocumentCode": 1,      "DocumentName": "doc1"    },    {      "ProcessCode": "09c27913-98cf-e711-80f3-1458d0431600",      "ProcessName": "processY",      "DocumentCode": 2,      "DocumentName": "doc2"    }];

let result = Object.values(types.reduce((a, {ProcessCode, ProcessName, DocumentCode, DocumentName}) => {
  (a[ProcessCode] || (a[ProcessCode] = {ProcessCode, ProcessName, Docs: []})).Docs.push({DocumentCode, DocumentName});
  return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```